# "Super from singleton method that is defined to multiple classes is not supported"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the [Steam Condenser](http://koraktor.github.com/steam-condenser/) library with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.

I have the following code:

```
require "steam/servers/source_server" 

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    server = SourceServer.new(IPAddr.new("127.0.0.1"), 2000)
    server.init

    @m = server.get_players
  end
end
```

but for some reason it throws:

> super from singleton method that is
>   defined to multiple classes is not
>   supported; this will be fixed in 1.9.3
>   or later

... on line 5: `server = SourceServer.new(IPAddr.new("127.0.0.1"), 2000)`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of Steam Condenser.

This is a shortcoming of Ruby 1.9.2 (as mentioned in the error message). There's already a [workaround for this issue](http://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser/issues#issue/65).

A real fix (eliminating the unusual Ruby code) will be made soon.